# NEMA 17 stepper motor

Tags: motor, stepper-motor

I'm going to use 4 **NEMA 17** stepper motors to build a **quadcopter**. I need to find the maximum upthrust that a single motor can give with a propeller of length 6cm (end to end). The holding torque of the motor is 53 N/cm.

Comment: Sounds like physics to me, not electronics.

Comment: usually quadcopters are made as Electronic projects rather than Physics projects.

Comment: migration candidate for physics.SE  [for the lack of aerodynamics stack at the moment of writing]

Comment: While there is some theoretic similarity between a stepper motor and the kinds of brushless DC motors normally used for this application, they are optimized for completely different purposes.   Steppers, designed for ease of positioning rather than speed, are hardly ever used in even ground based mobile applications, with the exception of one movement stage being carried atop another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The upthrust is dependant on the rpm of the motor and the pitch of the propeller. I don't think you will get enough lift with a stepper motor anyway becouse the rpm is too low even with a good driver. With a cheap driver you won't even get 1000 rpm and you need atleast 3000 rpm I think. Brushless DC motors are the way to go.

Comment: Yup. It's not going to work. OP needs to learn the basic physics before settling on motors.